# Show image using openGLES in QGlWidget

Tags: opengl-es, qt4

```
void GLMouseWidget::paintGL(QImage* data)
{
    //glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    //gldata = QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(*data);
    //glDrawPixels(data->width(), data->height(), GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, gldata.bits());

}
```

This code works fine under cards that support OpenGL, but not OpenGL ES1\2. I have read that I should try using textures, but I failed so far. Can someone share a code snippet? My images are gray-cycled (QImage::Format_Indexed8), I need +- efficient code snippet, just for showing the image on top of the QGLWidget.

Comment: Which part of the code is not working? What have you tried with textures?

Comment: i have no back-ground in open-gl at all. the only reason i am trying using qlwidget is the fact that without this i am having very bad Screen tearing, i read that in qt qlwidget preforms v-sync(if the video card supports this), a i really need is capture from a webcam, so all i am asking is help with few lins of code, how do i show qimage using textures in opengl.  bindTexture(*data,GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_RGB); //GL_LUMINANCE
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);
   glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0,  data->width(),data->height(),  GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data->bits() ); this is what i tried.

Comment: for now i do not have intentions leaning opnegl, so i just need help with this few lines of code, to see if this solves the screen tearing thing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so this is the way do do this in qt4.

```
GLMouseWidget::GLMouseWidget( int camWidth,int camHeight, QWidget* parent, Qt::WindowFlags f )
    : QGLWidget( parent, 0, f )
{
    qrf = QRectF (0.0f,0.0f,(float)camWidth,(float)camHeight);
   //qrf = QRectF (0.0f,0.0f,800.0f,600.0f);
}

void GLMouseWidget::setNewFrame(QImage *image_){
    glimage = QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(*image_);
    textureId = bindTexture(glimage);
}

void GLMouseWidget::paintGL()
{
    drawTexture(qrf, textureId);
}

void GLMouseWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport (0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, w,0,h,-1,1);
    glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

and from out of the class you call

```
*img = cvMatToQImage(frame);
label->setNewFrame(img);
label->update();
```